# NoSuchMethodError when compiling the source code

Tags: java

```
class Box {
  double weight;
  double height;
  double depth;

  Box(Box ob){
    weight = ob.weight;
    height = ob.height;
    depth = ob.depth;
  }

  Box(double w, double h, double d){
    weight = w;
    height = h;
    depth = d;
  }

  Box() {
    weight = -1;
    height = -1;
    depth = -1;
  }

  Box(double len){
    weight = height = depth = len;
  }

  double volume(){
    return weight * height * depth; 
  }
}

 public class OverloadConss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Box mybox1 = new Box (15,20,10);
            Box mybox2 =  new Box ();
            Box mycube = new Box(7);
            Box myclone =  new Box (mybox1);
            double vol;
            vol = mybox1.volume();
            System.out.println("The volume of the first box: " + vol);
            vol = mybox2.volume();
            System.out.println("The volume of the second box: " + vol);
            vol = mycube.volume();
            System.out.println("The volume of the mycube: " + vol);
            vol = myclone.volume();
           System.out.println("The clone of the mybox1:" + vol);
    }
}
```

When I compile the source code I got the message:

> Java/Eclipse/Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Box.(LBox;)at OverloadConss.main(OverloadConss.java:33)

Comment: which row is the row 33? (I'm guessing this one:  Box myclone =  new Box (mybox1); )

Comment: Ddi you put the entire source code (both classes) in the same file? If so, did you name the class `OverloadConss.java`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with your code; I run it without any error in eclipse. Output:

```
The volume of the first box: 3000.0
The volume of the second box: -1.0
The volume of the mycube: 343.0
The clone of the mybox1:3000.0
```

What are you using to run the script? If you using eclipse; try rebuilding workspace or rewriting the files (copy + paste).

Note: I would use something like this for Box.java so you only has to change 1 constructor if you change the datastructur.

```
class Box {
  double weight;
  double height;
  double depth;

  Box(Box ob){
    this(ob.weight, ob.height, ob.depth);
  }

  Box(double w, double h, double d){
    weight = w;
    height = h;
    depth = d;
  }

  Box() {
    this(-1, -1, -1);
  }

  Box(double len){
    this(len, len, len);
  }

  // additional methods
}
```

Comment: Yep, same for me. Works from Eclipse.

Comment: The first constructor should be Box(Box ob){ this(ob.weight, ob.height, ob.depth);}

Comment: Well, I am using Eclipse as an IDE but it seems that I have the same problem .

Comment: same with netbeans.Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put different classes in different .java-files, and it should work.

Comment: -1. No that is not necessary. There can be multiple classes in a single file.

Comment: This it not always true. You can only have one public class per Java file. The Java file can contain several other non public classes.

Comment: @vanje only one public top-level class. There can be *nested* public classes are ok.

Comment: In this case only `OverloadConss` is a public class and so both of them can be contained in a single file.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: Yes you are right. Nested classes can be publi, too.

Comment: I believe that my problem is  here  " Box myclone =  new Box (mybox1); "

Comment: @Sibbo why do you say so? I actually think that if they are all in a single file then OP would *not* get the error because every time on class is compiled so will the other.

Comment: Because, for me, when I put the classes in to different files, it worked, if I don't, it shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are in the same file then I don't see how this can happen. `OverloadConss.main` is called a `Box` constructor that is defined.

If they are in two separate files then my guess is that you added `Box.Box(Box)` recently and have not recompiled `Box.java` after that. Java is able to access some Box class so you are not getting `ClassNotFoundException`

Your best bet is to delete all `.class` files and recompile.